# Implementing RecyclerView and modifying the recycler items

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have a scenario where I use `RecyclerView`. Each recycler item contains an `Upload` button. `OnClick` of Upload I'm doing network operations (I upload data, images audio and video to server). So while uploading I want to display a message like `Uploading Data`, `Uploading Images` and so on. Currently my design is like this,

1. Each `RecyclerItem` is a card view and in that I have `ProgressBar` and `TextView` in a `Layout`. As I said I change the `TextView` content one after other.

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <ProgressBar
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/update_text_view"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/first"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/second"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingBottom="5dp"
       android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/third"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Upload"/>
    </LinearLayout> 
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
   ```

> Uploading all the content is a bigger process, So I have a separate
>   `Thread` class to do all these in background.

2. In RecyclerViewAdapter class I have methods to update the UI

   ```
   public void removeItem(String uniqueId) {
       if (recordMap != null && recordMap.keySet().size() > 0) {
           int pos = new ArrayList<>(recordMap.keySet()).indexOf(uniqueId);
           recordMap.remove(uniqueId);
           notifyItemRemoved(pos);
           notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, recordMap.keySet().size());
       }
   }

   public void failedItem(String uniqueId) {
       if (recordMap != null && recordMap.keySet().size() > 0) {
           int pos = new ArrayList<String>(recordMap.keySet()).indexOf(uniqueId);
           if (pos != -1) {
               LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                   R.layout.template_cardview, null, false);
               itemFailedFlag = true;
               bindViewHolder(new ViewHolder(view), pos);
               notifyItemChanged(pos);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Broadcast is registered (and unregistered) in specific `Fragment` where I have `RecyclerView` and I pass the `RecyclerViewAdapter` object to `BroadcastReceiver` class.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       if (mAdapter != null)
           mBroadcastReceiverClass = new BroadcastReceiverClass(mAdapter);

       if (mBroadcastReceiverClass != null)
           LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity())
               .registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiverClass, filter);
   }
   ```
4. I do all upload process in a `Thread` class, once the specific operation is completed, I broadcast message to registered Broadcast Receiver class.

   ```
   Intent mIntent = new Intent();
   mIntent.putExtra("uniqueId", uniqueId);
   mIntent.putExtra("fromFragment", "fragment_one");
   mIntent.setAction(context.getResources().getString(R.string.broadforcase));
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(mIntent);
   ```
5. `OnRecieve` of `Broadcast`, using the passed `RecyclerViewAdapter` object I call the methods defined in Adapter class.

   ```
    @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       String fromFragment = intent.getStringExtra("fromFragment");
       String uniqueId= intent.getStringExtra("uniqueId");
       String successResult = intent.getStringExtra("result");

       if (fromFragment != null) {
           if (fromFragment.equals("fragment_one")) {
               if (mAdapter != null) {
                  if (uniqueId!= null)
                      mAdapter.removeItem(uniqueId);
                  // Likewise call failedItem(uniqueId)
               }
           } else if (fromFragment.equals("fragment_two")) {
               if (mAdapter != null) {
                   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
           } else if (fromFragment.equals("fragment_three")) {
               if (mAdapter != null) {
                   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

> Also consider, the upload process will not block the UI (such like `ProgressDialog`, it's totally of background process). So the user are allowed to upload multiple recycler item data at the same time.

Here, everything is working as expected.

But the approach I implemented is right? Or this can be improved by any means?